# laplace transform of $ u(t-1)sin(\pi t) $

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm having difficulties with finding laplace transform of $ u(t-1)sin(\pi t) $

The answer I got is $\frac{\pi e^{-s}}{s^2+\pi^2}$, but the  correct one is $\frac{-\pi e^{-s}}{s^2+\pi^2}$ ,

I don't understand where does the negative sign come from.

thank you

Comment: Which method are you using to find your Laplace Transforms? Via a table? If so, applying the following works for me:
$$f(t)=u(t-c)g(t)\qquad F(s)=e^{-cs}\mathcal{L}\{g(t+c)\}$$
$$f(t)=\sin(at+b) \qquad F(s)=\frac{s\sin(b)+a\cos(b)}{s^2+a^2}$$
Where $F(s)=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$.

Comment: Currently, it is very difficult to tell where you went wrong in your calculation. Could you please show us all the steps you took to get to the answer you got? It would really help us determine where the mistake is if you do so.